# Syncing NSFetchedResultsController with UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

In my chat app, "lastMessage" is a relationship between the entities Friend and messages. Each Friend entity has a set of messages and only one lastMessage. Therefore, if i send a message to bill, bill's "lastMessage" will be updated to a newer Timestamp. That said, fetchedResultsController's fetched objects contains an array of each friend's lastMessage.timestamp . The problem I'm having is with the UITableView. If I message a friend a message in the chattingController and press back while simply having "messageTable.reloadData" inside of DidChangeContent, the friend I messaged, his lastMessage is updated to the latest timestamp and is sorted to be the first entry in the fetchedResultsController, moving him in the first spot in the tableview. However, as I wish to add animation by using   self.messagesTable.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None) inside of didChangeObject, nothing is reloading properly. I tried putting it in .Insert, .Update, and .Move all at once. I'm fairly new to syncing NSFetchedResultsController to a tableView. So I'm not sure how reloading a  table is normally achieved with NSFetchedResultsController.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var messagesTable: UITableView!

lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Friend")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastMessage.timestamp", ascending: false)]
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "lastMessage.timestamp != nil")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    frc.delegate = self
    return frc

}()



func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    if type == .Insert {

        self.messagesTable.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)//reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!])
        self.messagesTable.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)//reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!])


    }

    if type == .Update{
        // self.collectionView?.cha([newIndexPath!])
        print("h")
        self.messagesTable.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)//reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!])
        self.messagesTable.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)//reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!])


    }

    if type == .Move{
        // self.collectionView?.cha([newIndexPath!])
        print("h")
        self.messagesTable.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)//reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!])
        self.messagesTable.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)//reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!])


    }

}


func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {

    self.messagesTable.beginUpdates()


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`, use the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` methods.  Also, use `beginUpdates` in the `controllerWillChangeContent` method, and `endUpdates` in `controllerDidChangeContent`.  For example:

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.messagesTable.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
        case .Insert:
            self.messagesTable.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Delete:
            self.messagesTable.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        default:
            return
    }
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    switch type {
        case .Insert:
            self.messagesTable.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Delete:
            self.messagesTable.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Update:
            self.messagesTable.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Move:
            self.messagesTable.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            self.messagesTable.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.messagesTable.endUpdates()
}
```